# How to Get users header pictures (or cover picture), also known as banner?

Tags: tweetinvi

I'm using Tweetinvi API to get access to Twitter's API. What I want is to get the cover picture(or header picture or banner) using the API. So I tried

```
    var twitterCredentials = new TwitterCredentials(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    Tweetinvi.Auth.SetCredentials(twitterCredentials);
    _userProfile = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
```

The Method to get the banner is(so I think):

```
     _userProfile.ProfileBannerURL
```

but It is returning the background image that I used on Twitter not the header(or cover) picture.

Any Ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question. For those of you who countered this bug you are probably using the oldest version 0.9.13 or lower like I was doing. Update the API to version 1.0 or higher.